# jquery to show table row if input has a value. wrong keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I have some table rows with text inputs inside.
Each row has a unique name fp0,fp1,fp2,fp3...
The input is getting a value from a php array, but sometimes the array is empty, and has not value.
If the input has a value, then the TR should show.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This works fine<br>as long as has no default values set like a PHP variable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fp0">
        <td>
            <label>INPUT0:</label>
            <input type="text" class="fp" name="fp_name0" id="fp_name0" value="">
            <td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fp1">
        <td>
            <label>INPUT1:</label>
            <input type="text" class="fp" name="fp_name1" id="fp_name1" value="">
            <td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fp2">
        <td>
            <label>INPUT2:</label>
            <input type="text" class="fp" name="fp_name2" id="fp_name2" value="">
            <td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>If it has a value it should display and +1 empty input on the bottom.<br>
            If you delete INPUT10 Then INPUT11 Should hide.<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fp10">
        <td>
            <label>INPUT10:</label>
            <input type="text" class="fp" name="fp_name10" id="fp_name10" value="VALUE10">
            <td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fp11">
        <td>
            <label>INPUT11:</label>
            <input type="text" class="fp" name="fp_name11" id="fp_name11" value="">
            <td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fp12">
        <td>
            <label>INPUT12:</label>
            <input type="text" class="fp" name="fp_name12" id="fp_name12" value="">
            <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/*AS LONG AS NO VALUE IS SET, EVERYTING WORKS FINE*/
if ($("#fp_name0").val() !== "") {
    $('#fp1').show();
} else {
    $("#fp_name0").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") {
            $("#fp1").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#fp1").slideUp();
            $("#fp2").slideUp();
            $("#fp_name1").val("");
            $("#fp_name2").val("");
        }
    });
};
if ($("#fp_name1").val() !== "") {
    $('#fp2').show();
} else {
    $("#fp_name1").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") {
            $("#fp2").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#fp2").slideUp();
            $("#fp_name2").val("");
        }
    });
};

/*THIS HAS VALUES AND HAS PROBLEMS*/

if ($("#fp_name10").val() !== "") {
    $('#fp11').show();
} else {
    $("#fp_name10").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") {
            $("#fp11").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#fp11").slideUp();
            $("#fp12").slideUp();
            $("#fp_name11").val("");
            $("#fp_name12").val("");
        }
    });
};

if ($("#fp_name11").val() !== "") {
    $('#fp12').show();
} else {
    $("#fp_name11").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") {
            $("#fp12").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#fp12").slideUp();
            $("#fp_name12").val("");
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Its a bit hard to explain, but here is a 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khuu59ud/) of the code.

Comment: keyup function is working fine. Didn't find any issues

Comment: Do you want to show the trs automatically when the page has been loaded, without keyup?

Comment: @PrakashLaxkar Yes it works, but if the input has a value, it should show. the second input only shows if you do a keyup on the first.

Comment: @Teemu yes! if the input has a value, the TR should show on pageload.

Comment: I think two elements are enough to illustrate your problem. It's much easier for people to help you when the code is as short as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked finally:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#fp_name10").val() !== "") {
        $('#fp11').show();
        $("#fp_name10").keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() !== "") {
                $("#fp11").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#fp11").slideUp();
                $("#fp12").slideUp();
                $("#fp_name11").val("");
                $("#fp_name12").val("");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#fp_name10").keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() !== "") {
                $("#fp11").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#fp11").slideUp();
                $("#fp12").slideUp();
                $("#fp_name11").val("");
                $("#fp_name12").val("");
            }
        });
    };

    if ($("#fp_name11").val() !== "") {
        $('#fp12').show();
        $("#fp_name11").keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() !== "") {
                $("#fp12").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#fp12").slideUp();
                $("#fp_name12").val("");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#fp_name11").keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() !== "") {
                $("#fp12").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#fp12").slideUp();
                $("#fp_name12").val("");
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) is what you are looking for. Place the code to hide or show the element in this event listener.

If you also want to set the visibility to the correct value when the element is loaded, you can call the same code from `onload` as well. It might be required to add the `onload` attribute to the input (instead of using jQuery, depending on when your jQuery code is executed).

Comment: No. It will only show the tr if I make a change. I would need to show it, if it has a value.

Comment: Within onchange you can check for the value.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the onload handler as well.

Answer (score 0):

First replace:

```
 this.value
```

with

```
$(this).val()
```

Because `this` changes meaning in a jQuery event.

Next, rather than using `keyup`, try on `change` instead.

```
$("#fp_name0").on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        $("#fp1").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#fp1").slideUp();
    }
});

$("#fp_name1").on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        $("#fp2").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#fp2").slideUp();
    }
});

$("#fp_name2").on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        $("#fp3").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#fp3").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: "Because this changes meaning in a jQuery event." It is not. `onchange` here is a bad idea, it changes the purpose of the code too ...

Comment: On change is not good. It shows the new row only if I click away. and doesnt display the rows if they have values from php.